# Conditional onbeforeunload event in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
    var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave the page. All data will be lost!';

    if (typeof evt === 'undefined') {
        evt = window.event;
    }
    if (evt && !($("#a_exit").click)) {
        evt.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
};
```

I want user to leave the page clicking to the link (has `id ="a_exit"`) only. In other circumstances such as refreshing the page, clicking another link, user will be prompted that if he/she wants to leave the page. I have tried to use the code above. It still asks me if I want to go away when I click the exit link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remove `window.onbeforeunload` in the click handler.

Comment: I was guessing it won't work but tested under last chrome, IE and FF and it works  http://jsfiddle.net/Suf99/

Answer (score 5):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function() {
    return "'Are you sure you want to leave the page. All data will be lost!";
});

$('#a_exit').live('click',function() {
    $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
```

Above works for me

Answer (score 4):

My quick example of the conditional prompt before leaving page:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit(event) {
        var messageText = tinymce.get('mMessageBody').getContent();
        messageText = messageText.trim();

        // ... whatever you want

        if (messageText != "")
            return true;
        else
            return void (0);
   };
```

It works under Chrome, FF.

Comment: Thanks lot. its working fine in IE9 and safari also. send custom message instead of return true in old browsers, use below line when fun return.
 `return _isSaved ? void (0) : "You have unsaved work on this window."`

Answer (score 4):

You can return `null` when you do not want the prompt to show. Tested on Chrome 79.

```
window.onbeforeunload = () =>  {
    if(shouldPrompt){
       return true
    }else{
       return null
    }
}
```

BTW modern browser no longer support custom onBeforeUnload promp text.

Answer (score 2):

It will **always** prompt you if you want to leave the page. It's a security issue and cannot be *worked-around*.
Moreover, anything you return in the `onbeforeunload` event handler that is not `void` will be treated as the message for the prompt. Refer to this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
   window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(someBoolean) {
    return 'message'
    }else{
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
    }
```

Comment: This works on IE11 as well whereas return null does not.

Answer (score 0):

How about a variable to decide, if the link was clicked?

```
var exitClicked = false;

$("#a_exit").click(function() {
  exitClicked = true;
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
  //...

  if(evt && !exitClicked) {
    evt.returnValue = message;
  }  

  //...
};
```

You only set `exitClicked = true` when the link was really clicked and afterwards, before unloading you can simply check this variable.

Comment: Sorry, it changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old but I wanted just to change the code given that .live is no longer working in Jquery. So, the updated version would be:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function() {
     return "'Are you sure you want to leave the page. All data will be lost!";
 });

 $('#a_exit').on("click", function(){
    $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
```